# WooCommerce custom settings tab validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When using a custom settings tab in WooCommerce, like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'add_my_custom_tab', 50);

function add_my_custom_tab($settings_tabs) {
    $settings_tabs['my_custom_tab'] = __('My Custom Tab', 'my-custom-tab');
    return $settings_tabs;
}

add_action('woocommerce_settings_tabs_my_custom_tab', 'my_custom_tab');

function my_custom_tab() {
    woocommerce_admin_fields(get_custom_settings());
}

add_action('woocommerce_update_options_my_custom_tab', 'update_my_custom_tab_settings');

function update_my_custom_tab_settings() {
    woocommerce_update_options(get_custom_settings());
}

function get_custom_settings() {
    $settings = array(
        'section_title' => array(
            'name' => __('Custom Options', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
            'type' => 'title',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => 'wc_custom_tab'
        ),
        'example_input' => array(
            'name' => __('My Input', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => 'wc_my_input'
        ),
        'section_end' => array(
            'type' => 'sectionend',
            'id' => 'wc_section_end'
        )
    );
    return apply_filters('wc_my_custom_tab_settings', $settings);
}
```

How can I perform custom validation on the example_input field before allowing it to save to the database, and, if needed, throw an error to tell the user what's wrong with the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make field required by just adding the html5 required attribute to the field.

```
'example_input' => array(
    'name' => __('My Input', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'desc' => '',
    'custom_attributes' => array( 'required' => 'required' )
    'id' => 'wc_my_input'
),
```

But in you case if you want to display error message on field update you can do something like this. add filter `woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_<option_name>`

```
// define the woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_<option_name> callback 
function filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_wc_my_input( $value, $option, $raw_value ) { 
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() use($value) {
        if($value == ""){
            echo '<div id="message" class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Option is required</p></div>';    
        }
    });
    return $value; 
}; 
// add the filter 
add_filter( "woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_wc_my_input", 'filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_wc_my_input', 10, 3 );
```

**Edit**

You can loop through all options like this

```
$options = ['wc_my_input' => 'My Input', 'other_field' => 'Other Field']; // get all the options here
foreach($options as $option_name => $option_val){
    // define the woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_$option_name callback 
    add_filter( "woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_$option_name", function($value, $option, $raw_value) use($option_val) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', function() use($value) {
            if($value == ""){
                echo "<div id=\"message\" class=\"notice notice-error is-dismissible\"><p>$option_val is required</p></div>";
            }
        });
        return $value;
    }, 10, 3 ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can I prevent the settings from saving if I echo the error message?

Comment: @OhMad you can do something like `return $value != "" ? $value: "";` by replacing `return $value` which will prevent updating the value.

Comment: Thank you, how about all the other options? I'd like to do a check not only on the single field, but the entirety of options (not one by one, but a single check at the end is enough, to know if the user is allowed to save the settings or not).

Comment: Thank you. Getting back to my previous question, I still see the "your settings have been saved" message. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Just a little improvement: instead of using the *admin_notices* hook, you should use *WC_Admin_Settings::add_error('My error')* static method

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to meet your requirement with simple filter option available in woo-commerce.

I have added only one more filter and basic login on that filter. Filter name is `woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option`

you need to apply your logic on this filter which will do everything as per your need.

you can prevent saving of the option if there is an error by setting empty value and then show notice for that field too.

I have aded one custom attributes to do validation and the name of the attribute is 'custom_validate'
If there is an empty field then below attributes value prevent from storing data.

```
'custom_attributes' => array( 
    'required' => 'required' 
)
```

Put whole code snippet in your functions.php and start tracing the flow. Hope you will get it

```
// define the woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option callback 
function filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option( $value, $option, $raw_value ) { 

/*Try to print data as given below to study and decide logic to implement*/    

/*
    echo "<pre style='margin-left:500px'>";
    echo "Value";
    print_r($value);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre style='margin-left:500px'>";
    echo "Option";
    print_r($option);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre style='margin-left:500px'>";
    echo "Raw";
    print_r($raw_value);
    echo "</pre>";
*/

$error = false;
$message = "";
$custom_validate    = $option['custom_validate'];
$required           = $option['custom_attributes']['required'];
$name               = $option['name'];

if($custom_validate == 'yes'){
    if($required == 'required' ){
        //Do your validation here and set error notice for the same
        $message =  "<div id=\"message\" class=\"notice notice-error is-dismissible\"><p>$name is required</p></div>";
        $error = true;
    }   
}

/*If there is an error then empty the value and show the notice for that input*/
add_action( 'admin_notices', function() use($message) {
    if(!empty($message))
        echo $message;
});

if($error)
    return "";

/*If no error then it will return the default value*/
return $value; 
 }; 

 // add the filter 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option', 10, 3 );


  add_filter('woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'add_my_custom_tab', 50);

  function add_my_custom_tab($settings_tabs) {
$settings_tabs['my_custom_tab'] = __('My Custom Tab', 'my-custom-tab');
return $settings_tabs;
}

  add_action('woocommerce_settings_tabs_my_custom_tab', 'my_custom_tab');

  function my_custom_tab() {
   woocommerce_admin_fields(get_custom_settings());
  }

  add_action('woocommerce_update_options_my_custom_tab', 'update_my_custom_tab_settings');

  function update_my_custom_tab_settings() {
   woocommerce_update_options(get_custom_settings());
 }

 function get_custom_settings() {
$settings = array(

    'section_title' => array(
        'name' => __('Custom Options', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
        'type' => 'title',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => 'wc_custom_tab'
    ),

    'example_input' => array(
        'name' => __('My Input', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => '',

        'id' => 'wc_my_input_1',
        'custom_attributes' => array( 
                            'required' => 'required' 
                        )
    ),

    /*You can pass any number of custom attributes and based on those attribures you can develop your logic for validation*/
    /*'custom_validate' is a custom attribute that is used to identify whether i need to do custom validation or not*/
    'example_input_2' => array(
        'name' => __('My Input 2', 'woocommerce-my-custom-tab'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'desc' => '',
        'custom_validate' => 'yes',
        'id' => 'wc_my_input_2',
        'custom_attributes' => array( 
                            'required' => 'required' 
                        )
    ),

    'section_end' => array(
        'type' => 'sectionend',
        'id' => 'wc_section_end'
    )
);
return apply_filters('wc_my_custom_tab_settings', $settings);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that printing something with `admin_notices` hook inside `woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_` is such a good idea.

I am pretty sure that we can use `add_error()` static method of `WC_Admin_Settings` instead.

The same example but wth my approach:

```
$options = array( 'wc_my_input' => 'My Input', 'other_field' => 'Other Field' );
foreach( $options as $option_name => $option_val ){
    add_filter( "woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_$option_name", function( $value ) {
       
        if( ! $value ){
            WC_Admin_Settings::add_error( 'Required field!' );
            return null;
        }

        return $value;
    } ); 
}
```

A little bit more information about WooCommerce custom settings validation: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/custom-settings-validation.html