# Display error message on validation of an text input field of a custom woocommerce settings plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've read the following question and answers on the following stackoverflow page
[Custom tab validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370947/woocommerce-custom-settings-tab-validation)

I want to display an error message when the license key of my woocommerce admin settings plugin is invalid.

The validation code of the license key is working but i can't get to display a message if the key is wrong.

See the following code:

```
    function filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_tlicense( $value, $option, $raw_value ) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() use($value) {

            echo '<div id="message" class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Wrong license key</p></div>';

    });
   return $value;
};
// add the filter
add_filter( "woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_tlicense", 'filter_woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_tlicense', 10, 3 );
```

I left out the code to check if the key is wright, that's working.

I don't see the message appear but if I use the chrome inspector the html is there.

How can I get to display an error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for an error:

```
 WC_Admin_Settings::add_error( esc_html__( 'Ongeldige licentie sleutel!', 'restaurant-nybe' ) );
```

For a regular message:

```
WC_Admin_Settings::add_message( esc_html__( 'De plugin Restaurant nybe is geactiveerd. Geldige licentie sleutel!', 'restaurant-nybe' ) );
```